# Using Visual Studio Code and using defined symbols

Tags: c#, constants, csproj, visual-studio-code

EDIT: I have edited the whole question, since this is not only for Unity3D, but at all .sln projects.

I have a installation of Visual Studio Code(Not Visual Studio, but this:https://code.visualstudio.com/) on my Macbook at work. VSCode is otherwise working just fine with normal and Unity3D projects. I get Intellisense on all classes, including Unity3D specific ones, like GameObject. So I think my installation and startup sequence is correct.

Only problem I have, is that VSCode does not seem to recognize constants defined in the .csproj files. First I noticed this with some Unity3D plugins, but it is persistent on normal Visual Studio projects too.

My sample project is a dummy application downloaded from internet, but it is fully working on MonoDevelop. This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DummyConsoleApplication
    {
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                tester();
            }

            #if DEBUG
            static void tester(){

            }
            #endif
        }
    }
```

The function call in Main causes a not found exception on the editor, but it compiles fine, since the .csproj file has this line:

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
```

Any verification on if this is normal behaviour for VSCode would be greately appreciated. Also, if anyone is aware of any solution, even hacky ones, to get past this bug and force Intellisense to autocomplete would help out too.

The error I get is:

```
The name 'tester' does not exist in the current context [DummyConsoleApplication]
```

My hardware is a Macbook with Yosemite and my compiler is dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta4.

Comment: Could it have something to do with line endings?  You have to convert line endings when you use Visual Studio code in Unity.  and yes, MonoDevelop is a nightmare.

Comment: Well that is something I have not done yet. Could you point me to a right direction on how to do this?

Comment: I think I got the line endings converted. I used a LineBreak named utility to do it. Did not fix the error. If you are using VSCode, could you check the behaviour in your enviroment?

Comment: The links speak fully of Visual Studio and not VSCode, so they are not helpful in my situation. And yes, MonoDevelop noticed the line ending changes. I tried mac, win and unix endings with the LineBreak tool And none helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation with [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/), the C# engine that Visual Studio Code is [built around](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages).  There is an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/226) for adding `<DefineConstants>` support, but it is tied to a larger issue with regards to [MSBuild Support](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/226).

Currently, this isn't a supported configuration under Visual Studio Code.  You can try to define your constants through the [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging) instead, but support is minimal at best.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it is not in my enviroment. Could you give me any more info on defining them in lauch.json? I would be happy if I just got VSCode to not give an error when calling methods inside "#if UNITY_ANDROID" -tags.

Answer (score 3):

It should work...

As a sanity check, have you:

- "Sync MonoDevelop Project" recently?
- Make sure Visual Studio Code has the **-csharp** solution (.sln) selected? (Click the flame in the status bar to change)

Comment: Yes. I did the sync, opened the project folder containing .sln files and selected the project from the flame at the bottom. Intellisense is working fine and dandy. Does your VSCode recognize those tags defined by Unity?